# mysql queries - performance loss by putting numbers in quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

If a variable will always be a number, is there a performace loss by putting it in inverted commas?

for example

```
"SELECT prod.product_name FROM prod WHERE prod.id = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, you won't have any performance loss by putting them inside inverted commas. But do take care of **sql injections** in such kind of queries. Also note that performance means many things, you've to be specific. Generally, it works fine.

Comment: +1: Single quote values against columns with numeric data types have implicit conversion performed -- means you don't have to use CAST.